# Xbox 360 controller is not working on my Moto E4 Plus

Tags: usb-on-the-go, game-controllers

I don't know what happened. My USB OTG cable is working fine and also my Xbox controller on PC. In fact, I have another Android, Sony Xperia Z3 plus. Here it's working just fine. But I don't know what prevent to do so in E4 Plus.
Any ideas

Comment: _I don't know what happened._ Do you mean it was working before and it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Actually xbox360 gamepad is working just fine through Bluetooth

Comment: So try to connect it through Bluetooth instead of USB cable as your phone might not be compatible with USB OTG. Edit: Turns out the phone support USB OTG (just checked), so the issue might be with the cable or the phone connector.